# How to recover Python on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, python, python-2.7

I've accidentally removed `/user/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on ubuntu 12.10. Do I need to reinstall python?

Some of the softwares like ibus or software center seem don't work any more.

What should I do to recover that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove the python package that will remove ubuntu-desktop also. after that install ubuntu-desktop 
everything will be fine

Comment: Please elaborate your answers.

Comment: I tried reinstall ubuntu-desktop, doesn't work